# Why there is no dedicated Python community?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, site-proposal

I was wondering why there is no dedicated python community in Stack Exchange like Drupal, Android etc? Isn't the language (Python) popular enough?

I am a Python user since last year. Would like to know more about this language and different problems faced by other programmers.

Comment: Drupal and Android are not languages.

Comment: Well Drupal is PHP based and Android is Java based. So why they deserve dedicated community unlike Python?

Comment: Because people asked for them on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), where they got enough support to become sites. Again - because general Drupal & Android questions don't belong on Stack Overflow, these are topics that can have a separate site (you really should look at those sites and what questions are asked on them).

Comment: We already have Stack Overflow for specific questions and Programmers for broader discussion and Documentation for something(?) and Chat for community, you really want the experts to divide their attention even more?

Comment: have you tried just following the python tag on SO?

Answer (score 7):

> Isn't the language (Python) popular enough?

Well, yes. Large enough to have a staggering [631,064 questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

The problem with your assumption is that Android and Drupal aren't programming languages. Programming-related questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow already, so no need for a dedicated Python site.

Android programming questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow too; usage questions aren't. Such questions are on-topic on Android.SE. See, there is not complete overlap; those sites complete each other. The same is more or less true for Drupal.SE, although it seems that programming is on-topic on Drupal.SE too.

Comment: There is a significant overlap between the Drupal tag on SO and the Drupal site, all questions about developing with Drupal are on-topic on both. But there are also questions about administration of Drupal that aren't on-topic on SO, so the Drupal site is not a complete subset of SO

Comment: Good point. Generally my post is true though. @MadScientist

Answer (score 3):

There are sites in the SE network that are about a programming language or a tool commonly used for programming, which would make them on-topic on Stack Overflow. Examples: [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com), [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), [Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/), [Vim.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

These sites have been proposed because people thought it was a good idea to start a new site with a bit more autonomy, visibility and sense of community than a tag or group of tags on Stack Overflow.

Such a proposal could also have been made for Python, it would surely be viable and perhaps more manageable than the current situation with Python both contributing to and suffering from scale issues on SO.

But a proposal wasn't made - maybe because Python is such a mainstream language that people feel it belongs on SO, maybe because there isn't such a strong sense of community compared to the niche topics mentioned above, or maybe for some completely different reason. Now it is too late - with already 1.9 million questions on SO it would make no sense to start a new site only to suffer from cross-site duplicates and fragmentation of knowledge.